# ConstraintLayout with databinding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-constraintlayout

Is it possible to do something like this:

Xml:

```
        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
             app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="@{viewModel.guidelinePercent}"
        />
```

ViewModel:

```
  @Bindable
    public float getGuidelinePercent() {
        return condition ? 0.6f : 0.8f;
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot find the setter for attribute
>   'app:layout_constraintGuide_percent' with parameter type float on
>   android.support.constraint.Guideline.

I've tried with BindingAdaptor but it doesn't change the value:

ViewModel:

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"constraintPercent"})
public static void setConstraintPercent(Guideline view, float percent){
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.setGuidelinePercent(view.getId(), percent);
}
```

Xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
                 app:constraintPercent="@{viewModel.guidelinePercent}"
            />
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This issue may be related to [Android Databinding cannot set the layout_width (layout_height) property](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37054474). In any case, add the following code to `ViewModel`:

```
public float getGuidelinePercent() {
    return 0.5f; // Of course, this default could be anything you want.
}

@BindingAdapter("layout_constraintGuide_begin")
public static void setLayoutConstraintGuideBegin(Guideline guideline, float percent) {
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) guideline.getLayoutParams();
    params.guidePercent = percent;
    guideline.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

Your XML for the `Guideline` will look something like this:

```
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="@{viewModel.guidelinePercent}"/>
```

btw, thanks for this idea. I have been wanting an easier way to adjust guidelines programmatically.

Comment: Thank you that's the way to go, changing Guideline LayoutParams. Yup using a BindAdapter with the help of a Bindable to provide the parameters value is a powerful weapon and the only way to make ANY view configuration "databindable". :)

Comment: @GuilhE I was really addressing the setter error, but I guess the `LayoutParams` code was a bonus. :)

Answer (score 8):

The `ConstraintSet` you're creating should be set to the `ConstraintLayout` sometime after setting the percentile.

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"constraintPercent"})
public static void setConstraintPercent(Guideline view, float percent){
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) view.getParent();
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
    constraintSet.setGuidelinePercent(view.getId(), percent);
    constraintLayout.setConstraintSet(constraintSet);
}
```

Comment: This brilliantly concise technique can be used inside a click listener for example to dynamically show/hide everything to the left of the GuideLine!!!