# How best to re-size a ConstraintLayout by touch?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Consider a trivial *ConstraintLayout* with a 20% vertical *GuideLine* and a thick ugly vertical bar left of the invisible line (see XML).

I can manipulate the percentile programmatically by using *ConstraintSet.setGuidelinePercent()* as per [tynn's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44847951/2376004), but I need a more dynamic implementation (eg: a **draggable GuideLine or Barrier**).

Must be a better way than attaching a drag listener to the vertical bar and using *setGuidelinePercent()*?

It seems incomprehensible that *ConstraintLayout* would not provide a native solution - perhaps I just couldn't find it?

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leftTV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#AAA"
        android:text="LEFT: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/verticalBar"
        />

    <View android:id="@+id/verticalBar"
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideLine" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideLine"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".20" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rightTV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#DDD"
        android:text="RIGHT: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideLine"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [*MotionLayout*](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout). (Emphasis is mine.)

> MotionLayout is a layout type that helps you manage motion and widget animation in your app. MotionLayout is a subclass of ConstraintLayout and builds upon its rich layout capabilities. As part of the ConstraintLayout library, MotionLayout is available as a support library and is backwards-compatible to API level 14.
>
> In addition to describing transitions between layouts, MotionLayout lets you animate any layout properties, as well. Moreover, it inherently supports seekable transitions. This means that you can instantly **show any point within the transition based on some condition, such as touch input.**

Comment: Thank-you! Somehow it did not occur to me to google "How can a ConstraintLayout be animated?"